# Rails. Active Admin filter, based on model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin, arel, ransack

I want to create Active Admin filter that is using my model's instance method.

My model's name is simply `Item` and this model has method `used_in_widget?`, that returns `true` / `false` of course.

Now, I want to create an Active Admin filter that is represented by a select, with `Any`, `Yes` and `No` options.

My filter's code:

`filter :used_in_widget, as: :select, collection: { 'Yes' => true, 'No' => false }`

I know I should user ransack.

Here is my simplified model with ransack code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :used_in_widget_eq, -> (is) { all.select { |o| is == o.used_in_widget? } }

  ransacker :used_in_widget,
          formatter: proc { |v| used_in_widget_eq(v == 'true') } do |parent|
            parent.table[:id]
          end
```

That doesn't produce any error, but when I filter by `Yes` or `No` it returns 0 results.

I need advice, any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
def used_in_widget?
  grip.used_in_widget? || grip.decks.any?(&:used_in_widget?)
end
```

Comment: paste used_in_widget? method

Comment: @matanco I added that method. Look at edit

Comment: @TomaszGiba  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @CraigTreptow no, sorry

Comment: sad, I was looking exactly for this